# How to randomly place entities that don't overlap?

Tags: opengl, java, objects

I am creating a randomly-generated environment for a game I'm developing. I am using `OpenGL` and coding in `Java`.

I am trying to randomly place trees in my world (to create a forest), but I don't want the models to overlap (which happens when two trees are placed too close to each other). Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

I can provide more code if necessary, but here's the essential snippets. I am storing my objects in an `ArrayList` with `List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();`. I am then adding to that list using:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    entities.add(new Entity(tree, new Vector3f(random.nextFloat() * 800 - 400, 
    0, random.nextFloat() * -600), 0, random.nextFloat() * 360, 0, 3, 3, 3);
}
```

where each `Entity` follows the following syntax:

```
new Entity(modelName, positionVector(x, y, z), rotX, rotY, rotZ, scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
```

`rotX` is the rotation along the x-axis, and `scaleX` is the scale in the x-direction, etc.

You can see that I am placing these trees randomly with `random.nextFloat()` for the `x` and `z` positions, and bounding the range so the trees will appear in the desired location. However, I would like to somehow control these positions, so that if it tries to place a tree too close to a previously placed tree, it will recalculate a new random position. I was thinking that each tree `Entity` could have another field, such as `treeTrunkGirth`, and if a tree is placed in the distance between another tree's location and it's `treeTrunkGirth`, then it will recalculate a new position. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I am happy to add more code snippets and details as necessary.

Comment: Poisson disk sampling should do the work. Don't know if it's best for this and never really implemented/used it, but seems at least as a good start. Check this article: http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/

Comment: @Mars Wow, that link is super helpful, thanks. I'll see what I can do, and maybe come back with an answer of my own.

Comment: @Pikalek Yes, I think that question you linked is a duplicate. Would I just use the _xz-plane_ as the area for the "star map," like in the other question?

Comment: Yes, use the _xz_ plane in your case. Also, use `treeTrunkGirth` instead of a constant to determine the min distance for placing a tree if they need to vary.

Comment: @Pikalek If you add all that up in an answer, I'll select it as the best one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [Poisson-Disk sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling#Poisson_disc) distribution will allow you to select random points a minimum distance apart. Your situation is similar to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128801/how-would-i-go-about-generating-a-star-map), but since your trees aren't idealized points you'll need to change the distance checking as follows: the distance between a potential new tree & an existing tree, must be less than the sum of their radii.

[Bridson's algorithm](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf) can efficiently solve the problem in O(n), but it can be a bit fiddly to tweak it for variable distances. If your parameters are lowish &/or you are precomputing your terrain, a brute force solution may serve you just as well. Here's some sample code that brute forces the problem by checking every potential new tree placement against all prior placed trees:

```
public static class SimpleTree{
    float x;
    float z;
    float r;

    public SimpleTree(Random rng, float xMax, float zMax, float rMin, float rMax){
        x = rng.nextFloat() * xMax;
        z = rng.nextFloat() * zMax;
        r = rng.nextFloat() * (rMax-rMin) + rMin;
    }
}

private static ArrayList<SimpleTree> buildTreeList(float xMax, float zMax, 
        float rMin, float rMax, int maxAttempts, Random rng) {
    ArrayList<SimpleTree> result = new ArrayList<>();

    SimpleTree currentTree = new SimpleTree(rng, xMax, zMax, rMin, rMax);
    result.add(currentTree);

    boolean done = false;
    while(!done){
        int attemptCount = 0;
        boolean placedTree = false;
        Point nextPoint = new Point();
        SimpleTree nextTree = null;
        while(attemptCount < maxAttempts && !placedTree){
            attemptCount++;
            nextTree = new SimpleTree(rng, xMax, zMax, rMin, rMax);
            if(!tooClose(nextTree, result)){
                placedTree = true;
            }
        }
        if(placedTree){
            result.add(nextTree);
        }
        else{
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static boolean tooClose(SimpleTree tree, ArrayList<SimpleTree> treeList) {
    for(SimpleTree otherTree : treeList) {
        float xDiff = tree.x - otherTree.x;
        float zDiff = tree.z - otherTree.z;

        float dist = (float)Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (zDiff * zDiff));
        if(dist < tree.r + otherTree.r){
            return true;
        }
    }        
    return false;
}
```

With the following parameters:

```
 maxAttempts = 500;
 width = 300;
 height = 200;
 minSize = 2;
 maxSize = 15;
```

I was able to randomly place & render between 400-450 trees in under a second. Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: Is this using Poisson disk sampling?

Comment: Yes, I've edited to make that explicit.

Comment: Try to use math.pow on `tree.r + other tree.r`,2, instead of math.sqrt, sqrt is usually slower than pow

Comment: @Ferrybig Comparing squared distances is faster, but that doesn't change the fact that it's a brute force algorithm & will still be O(n^2). If a faster solution is required, use Bridson's algorithm. Also, using `Math.pow(x,2)` isn't necessarily any better/different than using `x*x` as [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144275/xx-vs-math-powx-2-java-performance).

Comment: I've had a similar issue with terrain and ensuring some decent spread and no overlap.  I had actually done a variation, in my version the tress/brush are randomly spread across the terrain area.  I then run an function post this to check the distances of every item against each other, where they were too close I pushed them apart.  This though will impinge possibly on other trees in the area.  I repeated this until I had no collisions.  it's slower but what I also had as a bonus were things such as clearings (not everywhere is covered!) and tree density seemed more "interesting".

Comment: This was exactly what i was thinking!